# Qt 5 Logging - defining category with QLoggingCategory

Tags: qt, logging, qt5, qstring, const-char

I have a problem with `QLoggingCategory(const char * category)`.

When I use it like:

```
QString rt = "3";
QString sv = "P";
QLoggingCategory dailyLogger(QString(rt+sv+"Logger").toStdString().c_str());
```

it doesn't work (my custom message handler doesn't recognize this category).

But when I use:

```
QLoggingCategory dailyLogger("3PLogger");
```

message handler sees the category.

Here's the handler function:

```
void myMessageOutput(QtMsgType type, const QMessageLogContext &context, const QString &msg)
{
    if (QString(context.category).contains("3"))
    {
        //some code
    }
}
```

Why does my computed category name not work?

Comment: Possible, because `QString(rt+sv+"Logger").toStdString().c_str()` - is a rvalue and it will be invalid at next code line.

Answer (score 2):

`QLoggingCategory` retains a copy of the `char*` pointer with which it's constructed.  The pointed-to characters must remain valid and constant for the life of the `QLoggingCategory` instance.

In your failing example, `c_str()` returns a temporary which is no longer valid after the `std::string` goes out of scope.  So the `QLoggingCategory` is now pointing at invalid memory (giving you Undefined Behaviour).

In your second example, you pass a string literal, which is valid for the lifetime of the program, so no lifetime issues arise.

You will need to copy the string data into a `char` array with a lifetime that outlives the logging category.